# Como meter una lista dentro de una cadena

Tags: python

Quisiera añadir una lista a una cadena, haciendo que quede así:

```
alumnos = [["Juan", "Silvia"], ["María", "Luisa"], ...]
```

No sé exactamente cómo hacerlo en python.

Comment: A que te refieres, muestra lo que tienes como entrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo directamente con el método `append` usando otra lista.

```
alumnos.append(["Otro", "Nombre"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Más simple es declarar la lista como variable y después usar print() para mostrarla:

```
alumnos = [["Juan", "Silvia"], ["María", "Luisa"], ...]
print("Lista de alumnos:" + alumnos)
```